# AWS CLI log in command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am starting into the AWS world and I recently configured my local environment to connect to my AWS account through the terminal, but I’m having a hard time finding the correct command to log in. Could someone  please point me how to do this.

Thank you beforehand

Comment: **TL;DR** you're probably looking for `aws configure` as pointed out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AWS CLI does not "log in". Rather, each individual request is authenticated with a set of credentials (similar to a username and password). It's a bit like making a phone call -- you do not need to "log in" to your telephone. Instead, the system is configured to already know who you are.

To store credentials for use with the AWS CLI, you can run the `aws configure` command. It will prompt you for an Access Key and Secret Key, which will be stored in a configuration file. These credentials will then be used with future AWS CLI commands.

If you are using your own AWS Account, you can obtain an Access Key and Secret Key by **creating an IAM User** in the Identity and Access Management (IAM) management console. Simply select **programmatic access** to obtain these credentials. You will need to assign appropriate permissions to this IAM User. (It is *not* recommended to use your root login for such purposes.)

Comment: I had to create some new credentials for the existing user I'm using, Idk why the first Access Key and Secret Key did not work

Comment: @JorgeHernandez the way IAM works each user has different permissions. If you needed to create a new IAM user, its because the first one you tried didn't have the right level of permissions to do what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

to login using shell you will need:

- IAM keys (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-access-key/)
- AWS Cli (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)